# Pythonic way of finding where a value is in a list of ranges

Tags: python, list, search, range

I have a list of start and end value dicts:

```
a = [
      {'start': 1, 'end': 3},
      {'start': 5, 'end': 6},
      {'start': 8, 'end': 10}
    ]
```

The list is guaranteed to be in order, and not have any overlap.  Given a value, I need to find where in the list it falls.  If it is in one of the defined ranges, I need to get the value back.  Otherwise, I need the next 'start' value in sequence.  e.g., given `b = 2`, I would get back the value `2` because it is in the first range.  However, given the value `b = 7` I would get back `8` as it is the start value for the next range in sequence from 7.

I have written some code to do this:

```
def where_in_range(v, val_ranges):
  # Check if v comes before all ranges
  if v < val_ranges[0]['start']:
    return val_ranges[0]['start']

  # Check if v is within one of the ranges
  for r in val_ranges:
    if v >= r['start'] and v <= r['end']:
      return v

  # Check if v is between ranges
  for i in range(0, len(val_ranges)-1):
    if v > val_ranges[i]['end'] and v < val_ranges[i+1]['start']:
      return val_ranges[i+1]['start']

  return None
```

But it seems quite non-pythonic.  I am willing to use a lightweight package, but something as heavy as pandas is out, as this is being embedded in a django application.  Any thoughts on how to make this more pythonic?

Comment: is using numpy ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check each range individually. Inter-range values are handled automatically, as are any pre-range values.

```
def where_in_range(v, val_ranges):
    for d in val_ranges:
        if v < d['start']:
            return d['start']
        elif v < d['end']:
            return v
```

Comment: Doh!  I wasn't seeing the forest for the trees.  This will work great, however I did add a `return None` after the for loop to handle the case where v is after the final range.  Thanks!

Comment: The function returns `None` implicitly if neither of the `return` statements executes, but there's no harm in adding it explicitly.